# Can't find local Docker images created with Go SDK

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to create some docker images on macOS (with Colima backend) using Go Docker SDK with following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive"
)

const dockerfile = `
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM golang:1.19-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

COPY . ./
RUN go mod download

RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN go install github.com/securego/gosec/v2/cmd/gosec@latest
RUN go install golang.org/x/vuln/cmd/govulncheck@latest
RUN go get github.com/stripe/safesql

CMD gosec ./... && govulncheck ./... && safesql ./...`

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    pathFlag := flag.String("path", ".", "path to the directory containing the go files")
    flag.Parse()
    if pathFlag == nil {
        log.Fatal("path flag is nil")
    }

    err := os.WriteFile(*pathFlag+"/Dockerfile", []byte(dockerfile), 0777)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to write file: %v", err)
    }

    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, " :unable to init client")
    }

    files, err := WalkMatch(*pathFlag, "*.go")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, " :unable to walk files")
    }

    reader, err := archive.TarWithOptions(*pathFlag, &archive.TarOptions{
        IncludeFiles: append(files, []string{"go.mod", "go.sum", "Dockerfile"}...),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, " :unable to create tar")
    }

    imageBuildResponse, err := cli.ImageBuild(
        ctx,
        reader,
        types.ImageBuildOptions{
            Tags:       []string{"newname"},
            Context:    reader,
            Dockerfile: "Dockerfile",
        })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, " :unable to build docker image")
    }
    defer imageBuildResponse.Body.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, imageBuildResponse.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, " :unable to read image build response")
    }
}

func WalkMatch(root, pattern string) ([]string, error) {
    var matches []string
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        if matched, err := filepath.Match(pattern, filepath.Base(path)); err != nil {
            return err
        } else if matched {
            r, err := filepath.Rel(root, path)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            matches = append(matches, r)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return matches, nil
}
```

The creation seems to be successful:

```
{"aux":{"ID":"sha256:568d5aed149aa73d38b644f49f68590cc06222467be1e1c3b902792da39f6e24"}}
{"stream":"Successfully built 568d5aed149a\n"}
{"stream":"Successfully tagged newname:latest\n"}
```

However, I can't find these images anywhere, `docker run` states there are no images with such tag, `docker ls` tells me the same. Do I miss something crucial? Are there any macOS specific things I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

You are only building the images not running them so you should use the command

```
docker images
```

to get all the images present on your system.

```
docker ps
```

only gives back the images which are currently running